# When applying function to array, Error "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Tags: python, scipy

I used [`scipy.integrate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html) to get the value of the Fresnel integrals, and I now wish to plot the Cornu spiral. However, when I attempt to create an array with the value of the integral for multiple inputs, I get the error mentioned in the title. I can't see how what I'm doing has anything to do with the Truth value mentioned in the error.

My code:

```
def COSINTEGRAND(x):
    return math.cos((pi * x**2)/2)
def SININTEGRAND(x):
    return math.sin((pi * x**2)/2)
def COSINTEGRAL(u):
    return quad(COSINTEGRAND, 0, u)
def SININTEGRAL(u):
    return quad(SININTEGRAND, 0, u)

a = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
b = COSINTEGRAL(a)
print (b)
```

Any explanation of the error or methods to fix this would be appreciated. I got the same error when trying to plot the spiral directly- it appears to refer to a part of the `scipy.integrate` code

Comment: What is the `dtype` of the arrays here? are these numpy arrays? if so call `np.cos` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the functions you're using don't know how to handle numpy arrays.
This includes the `scipy.integrate.quad` function.

quad docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html#scipy.integrate.quad

Comment: That doesn't appear to have made a difference, unfortunately. I get an identical error when replacing math.cos and math.sin with np.cos and np.sin

Comment: scipy.integrate.quad's third argument (`u` in your `COSINTEGRAL`) also takes a regular float, rather than a numpy array.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Does this mean that for me to plot the value over multiple inputs, I would have to write a loop to run the function multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you can use  Fresnel integeals as implemented in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.fresnel.html